# How do I select a child node based off the contents of a same level child node?

Tags: xpath

For example I want to only select a child node if the other child has the contents "example":

```
<ul class='thisClass'>
    <ul class='OtherChild'>
        <strong> capture this text </strong>
    </ul>
    <label>example</lable>
</ul>
```

Basically it **needs** label's inner-text to equal "example" or I do not want the contents of the **strong**.

I'm fairly new to XPath and I'm not quite sure how to go about this.

Comment: The `following-sibling::` axis is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter parent `<ul>` node by it's `<label>` child like this :

```
//ul[@class='thisClass' and label='example']/ul/strong
```

Or you can filter child `<ul>` node by it's `following-sibling` :

```
//ul[@class='thisClass']/ul[following-sibling::label[.='example']]/strong
```